# Label text not updating (cocos2d)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a class which I intend to reuse for a game with multiple levels and I'm having a problem with updating the label text. Basically, I'm trying to reuse this class for 15 levels of a game. So initially the value of the label is 1 then it should increase by one after the level has been cleared then the class is reloaded with the updated text. This is how I'm trying to update my label:

```
GameScene *stage= [stage node];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:stage];

//stageNo is an integer that I pass to the label as it's text value. As long as its less that 15, it should go inside that code block.
if(stageNo < 15)
{
    stageNo = stageNo + 1;
    [stage.layer.stageLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", StageNo]];
}
```

This only works only once so if the default value of the label is 1, after the class is reloaded it becomes 2. After that, it's just stuck to 2. So my question is, how can I update the label text whenever the class is reloaded to increment by 1?

Comment: How/where do you set up the stageLabel initially?

Comment: I set it up on the header class as a CCLabelTTF then on the init method, I set stageNo to 1 then I added this: stageLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stageNo] fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:18];

Comment: Sounds like a scope issue. If you only create the stageLabel locally in your init method, the rest of the code is unaware of its existence. Try making it an ivar or property.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I've already made it a property at the header class by adding @property....*stageLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is most definitely a scope problem. According to your comments you've done the right thing and created a property called stageLabel. The only problem is when you set it up initially you are not retaining it. 
Instead of using

```
stageLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stageNo] fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:18];
```

you should use

```
self.stageLabel = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stageNo] fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:18];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this and I just noticed something, my integer is not incrementing after the +1. So it's just stuck at 2. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: From the code you've showed us it's hard to say. The actual if-statment and logic seems to do what it's supposed to. The question is of course how/when do you call the method where this update is made and could you possibly be resetting the value somewhere before you increase it?

Comment: The update method is called when the the stage is cleared, then it reloads the entire class for the next stage. I tried removing the value I set for stageNo on the init method and that's not it.

Comment: Well, if you initing a new instance of the class, then obviously it will begin fresh for any variable that is set internally. Not having detailed knowledge of your project it's hard to know where to begin, but it sounds like you might have to rethink your model, or at the very least where you actually store some of this information. StageNo, Score, and numberOfLives are _some_ variables I would personally think belongs in a gameState-class of some sort...

Comment: I just tried the answer you added and it still doesn't work. StageNo does not increment after adding 1.

Comment: As I per my previous comment, it sounds like you need to rethink your model somewhat. If you create a new instance of the class every time you change levels you need to have another class keeping _track_ of these values. This probably makes for a better model as well, as you're actually separating the handling of data and visuals.

Comment: You're right. That's what I just tried and it works. I just added another class that keeps track of the level so it can change every time. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Separate the UILabel declaration from stringWithFormat in the init(). it then should work

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you but from what I understand, here's what I did: stageNo = stageNo + 1;
    NSString *strNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", stageNo];
    [stage.layer.stageLabel setString:strNo]; but that didn't work

Comment: You need to initialize stageLabel  in the init() like this stageLabel = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stageNo] fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:18];